# WPF Treeview data binding - does not exist in namespace

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to bind a datasource to a WPF Treeview

The class I'm binding to, exposes the property "ServerName", but even though, once I map the namespace and then with the help of code-completion select the class within this namespace to bind to, VS still complains that the class cannot be found in the ns. This is despite the fact that the class is assigned using code completion - SO IT CAN FIND IT!

code is as follows

```
 xmlns:self="clr-namespace:PracticonAlarmManager".....>

<TreeView Name="tvMonitoredAlarms" Height="272" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="683">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:MonitoredServer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServerName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

The Class is MonitoredServer, which I selected via the dropdown code completion list. It has a property called ServerName.

Can anyone please help? Whey does VS think the class cannot be found in the namespace when it allows me to assign it via the code completion list? Does this not contradict the error message?

Thanks

MM

EDIT : this works fine at run-time, I just have a broken editor ("invalid markup" etc)

Comment: Just rebuild your project

Answer (score 1):

Solution

Close VS, reboot, rebuild, close, reboot. Works.

Comment: Clean solution, then rebuild solution can work as well